# how to solve this error of button not showing up

Tags: javascript, php

Im building a table with php and that has a button inside, that on click calls a function passing parameters. the problem is that it isn't showing up in this way:

```
'<th><button type="button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="requestUserData(\''.$dataOra.'\')>Prenota</button></th>'
```

and it shows in this way :

```
'<th><button type="button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="requestUserData('.$dataOra.')>Prenota</button></th>'
```

complete more info of table maybe im doing something wrong here :

```
      $table.="<tr>
      <form id=".$i.">
      <td>".$i."</td>
      <td>".$dataOra."</td>".
      '<th><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="requestUserData('."'".$dataOra."'".')>Prenota</button></th>
    </form>
    </tr>';
```

what showing in html : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEg3R.png
However $dataOra is a string so how can I add ' - ' without losing the button?

Comment: Is there a missing quote in `type="button class`?

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for letting me know didnt saw it :)

Comment: Try adding single quotes using `"'"`, see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```php
'<th><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="requestUserData('."'".$dataOra."'".')">Prenota</button></th>'
```

Note that I have added an extra `"` after `type="button` to correct your HTML, and another `"` to close the `onclick` attribute.

In PHP, it's fine to add two strings that have different quotes around them, eg. `'hello'."world"`.

You can therefore add a string like `'this'` to a single quote like this `"'"`. This will get you a single quote in a string with single quotes around it, something that is usually only possible if you escape the character with a `\` (something which appears to be problematic for you).

Comment: it doesn't showing :(

Comment: @Singh Strange ... quotes not showing up in page source? Sorry I wasn't able to help

Comment: i have update answer with more info of table

Comment: Your answer is correct is was only missing one " ; now everything working ...Corrected                    <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="requestUserData('."'".$dataOra."'".')">Prenota</button></th>

Comment: @Singh Well noticed, I'm glad it works now! I've also edited my answer to be correct for anyone who visits this post in the future.